# WordPress : Enable Pretty Permalinks on manually installed apache server

Tags: wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite, permalinks, friendly-url

I have installed Apache server manually and also installed WordPress in it. When I enable pretty permalinks it does  not work. I also tried after enabling  `mod_rewrite` but the problem remains the same.

Comment: Have to look here: [5-simple-steps-to-configure-wordpress-to-use-permalinks-on-an-ubuntu-server](http://mixeduperic.com/ubuntu/5-simple-steps-to-configure-wordpress-to-use-permalinks-on-an-ubuntu-server.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add AllowOverride All to **Directory** directive to enable .htaccess

Comment: can you please guide me the directory path

Comment: Check either in your apache2.conf or your VirtualHost file for this - it should point to your wordpress documentRoot.

Comment: I have installed apache2.4. I found the AllowOverride in line no. 376 in httpd.conf file inside conf folder.

Comment: I have added AllowOverride All to Directory directive and also there is rule defined in _.htaccess_ file. But still the permalink is not working. Is there any other location where I should have to fix?